# How to access class members from a method?

Tags: c++, class, scope

I want to access the engine from inside my eventReceiver object.  They are fellow members of the game class, but how do I reach it?

```
// game.h
class game
{
    public:
        game();
        3dEngine* engine;
        eventReceiver* receiver;
};

// eventReceiver.h
class eventReceiver 
{
    public:
        eventReceiver () {}
        virtual bool OnEvent (const SEvent& event)
        {
            ...
            case QUIT_BUTTON_PRESSED:
>>>             engine->quit();     // how to access engine from here??
                return true;
            ...
        }
};
```

Should I use 'this' ? I don't understand why receiver can't see the engine.

Comment: You have a lot of unnecessary stuffs in your post. Narrow it down. Close to downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Implement the class as a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) and write a getter for the `engine` property. Accessing code could then look like:

```
game::getInstance()->getEngine()->quit();
```

I would recommend you though, that you create a `quite()` method in the game class itself hiding implementation details and allowing you to handle overall application shutdown and not just of the `3dEngine`:

```
game::getInstance()->quit();
```

If you dont want to implement the `game` class as singleton you could also pass a reference/pointer of a `game` object to the constructor of your event handler:

```
class CloseButtonHandler : public eventHandler {
    game& game;

public:

    CloseButtonHandler(game& game) : game(game) {
    }

    virtual bool OnEvent(const SEvent& event){
         ...
         game.getEngine()->quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: So the solution to access is making it a *global*? (*Singleton* is just a fancier name for *global* with the additional restriction that only one instance can be alive...)

Comment: @David Rodriguez A `game` class looks like a global class to me, doesnt it? Besides that Im showing a way to access it in a "normal" pattern. I  just hope this isnt getting another "Singleton - A Antipattern" discussion.

Comment: It all depends on the context... I am quite sure that in Facebook, there is no single global `Game`. At any rate, even if there is a single game in the application, it need not be global (it could be created in `main` and passed around to the types that need to use it...) Globals are almost always worse than any other option that makes do without them, as they hide dependencies (what in your application depends on `game`?) and make the code much harder to reason about (why and where did my `game` state change? *anywhere*?)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas See, your opening a book here which doesnt fit into the limited comment space on stackoverflow. A Singleton is a commonly used pattern and i wouldnt know why not to propose it. Myself dont want to forward dozens of objects for configurations etc. Of course there are other ways. Just take a glance at EJBs and CDI. Im actually tired of fighting such abstract discussions without any substance. One just dont know the context of this question, so one has to guess and im still pretty sure that a singleton pattern fits quite good into this situation.

Answer (score 0):

The eventReceiver shouldn't know anything about the engine. That's a bad design. There are a few solutions. One reasonable solution is to derive `game` from `eventReceiver` since `game` can clearly receive events. You can then implement the game-specific `OnEvent` handler in `game` itself. From there you can call `engine->quit`.

Comment: No, I dont think one has to separate that much. The game class looks actually like a singleton; atleast it seems to be a class involved in the application cycle. Therefor it would be a design issue to put logic to react to a concrete button in such a class. This is totally wrong!

Comment: How about I create them separately in main and just pass the receiver a pointer to myGame:  game myGame;  \n  eventReceiver receiver (&myGame);  ?

Comment: @Paranaix: I would say that it's entirely reasonable to code the `Quit` functionality in class `game`. After all, _you are trying to exit the game_ !

Comment: @MSalters Thats not my point. I would favor such a design. But implementing the actually event handler inside the game class is wrong.  A game class is not an event handler.

Comment: @oringe: A big part of the problem is that `EventReceiver` is a poorly chosen name, and that in turn makes reasoning about it more complex (different people can understand different things). Say that it was a `Controller` (that receives and acts on events), then most people would agree that having a reference to the controlled `engine` would make a lot of sense... In the same way, it is not clear what `Game` represents in your design.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how elegant this design is, but it works.

I just separated the receiver from the game class and gave its constructor a pointer to the instance of myGame. (Thanks to Paranaix)

```
class eventReceiver {
    public:
        eventReceiver (game* gameInstance) : gamei(gameInstance)
        virtual bool OnEvent (...) 
            {...
            case QUIT_BUTTON_PRESSED:
                gamei.engine->quitGame();
            ...}
    private:
        game* gamei;
}

int main() {
    game myGame;
    eventReceiver receiver (&myGame);
}
```